# datadefinition on type string not found

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am new to VB 2010 and crystal reports, I have been trying to resolve this issue (public member datadefinition on type string not found) for couple weeks without avail.

I have search everywhere but the answers I have been getting do not solve the problem.  Please see code below:

```
Private Sub SetParamValue(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As String)
    Try
        Dim crPDV As ParameterDiscreteValue
        Dim crPFD As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crPFL As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crPV As ParameterValues

        crPFD = CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource.DataDefinition.ParameterFields

        crPFL = crPFD.Item(key)
        crPV = crPFL.CurrentValues
        crPDV = New ParameterDiscreteValue
        crPDV.Value = value
        crPV.Add(crPDV)
        crPFL.ApplyCurrentValues(crPV)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub LoadHeaderInfo()
    Try

        SetParamValue("XXXXXXX", mReportNo)
        SetParamValue("XXXXXXXX", gInput.Customer)
    End Try

End Sub
```

The array has 80 different values, the *.rpt file loads correctly, but while debugging i get the exception public member datadefinition on type string not found. Once the *.rpt file loads I have to input the data manually.

This question probable has been asked before, but like I mention I have searched and have not been able to solve the issue.  Can someone point me in the correct direction on how to solve this issue?

Comment: How about this:  var parameter = reportDocument.ParameterFields[parameterName];
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                parameter.CurrentValues.Clear();
                parameter.CurrentValues.Add(new ParameterDiscreteValue() { Value = parameterValue });
            }
            else
            {
                log.InfoFormat(
                    "Attempt to set the parameter '{0}' ignored because it does not exist",
                    parameterName);
            }

Comment: Most important from the above is ParameterFields[parametername].. I dont see this in your code.